# How to create Android widget without android SDK?

Tags: android, android-widget

How can I create an Android widget without using the Android SDK? I tried creating it with only Java and the Android sdk, but it crashed.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.durden.telecomwidget"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <reciever android:name="TelecomBalance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"></action>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widgetinfo" />
    </reciever>
</application>
```

widgetinfo.xml:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/main"
android:configure="com.example.android.ExampleAppWidgetConfigure" 
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical">
```

@layout/main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:id="@+id/widget_textview"
                android:text="Hello Widget"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your "attempt" which is crashed?

Comment: So, i write basic code for my widget, after I run it in emulator and I can't run it. I can't found it in widgets. Here console output: http://i.imgur.com/X9Xtj.png

Comment: My widget does nothing. Just I can't run it

Comment: "but it crashed" -- use the LogCat view in Eclipse to look at the stack trace associated with your "crash".

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a specific answer for you, your question is rather vague to begin with, but I can point you in a direction I think will be helpful: [Read the source, Luke](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html), [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) is the way that the SDK draws a `TextView`. It will give you insight into what you need to do.